# Need explantation about basic java operator :

Tags: java, operators, conditional-operator

```
/**
 * Returns all Comments of the given review
 * @param reviewId
 * @return Returns all Comments as Collection or an empty Collection, if no Comments exist
 */
protected ArrayList<Comment> getComments(String reviewId) {
    ArrayList<Comment> result = new ArrayList<Comment>();

    HashMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, Comment>> authorMap = commentDB.get(reviewId);
    if (authorMap != null) {
        for (TreeMap<Integer, Comment> x : authorMap.values()) {
            result.addAll(x.values());
        }
    }
    return result;
```

In the following code, I am not understanding what is the use of `:` in the line

```
  for (TreeMap<Integer, Comment> x : authorMap.values())
```

I know `:` is a conditional operator, but don't know what conditional operator it is and what is its use. I searched java operators in google but did not found this operator.